# How to select an image in a table row?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table on a page like so:

```
<table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Table_Name" class="schedule-table" cellspacing="1" border="0" style="width:100%;">
<tr>
    <td class="resource-header"><span class="resource-header-text">Personnel</span></td>
    <td class="resource-header"><span class="resource-header-text">Office</span></td>
    <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Tue<br>01</span></td><td class="dow"><span class="dow">Wed<br>02</span></td><td class="dow"><span class="dow">Thu<br>03</span></td><td class="dow"><span class="dow">Fri<br>04</span></td><td class="weekend"><span class="weekend-text">Sat<br>05</span></td><td class="weekend"><span class="weekend-text">Sun<br>06</span></td><td class="dow"><span class="dow">Mon<br>07</span></td>...and so on until end of month...<td class="dow"><span class="dow">Thu<br>31</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_8">
<td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">8</span></td>
<td class="resource" id="TD_Name"><img src="../../images/epas/working.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." id="imgProgress" /><span title="Lname, Fname " class="resource">Lname, Fname</span></td>
<td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td>
<td class="dow" id="TD_1" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=01-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>
<td class="dow" id="TD_2" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=02-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>
<td class="dow" id="TD_3" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=03-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>
<td class="dow" id="TD_4" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=04-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>
<td class="weekend" id="TD_5" onDblClick="location.href('.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=05-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>
<td class="weekend" id="TD_6" onDblClick="location.href('myurl.aspx?p=8&amp;e=0&amp;d=06-Mar-2011&amp;o=8&amp;v=A6OK');"></td>
    .
    .
    .
and so on until end of month
    .   
    .
    .
</tr>
    .
    .
    .
and a bunch more similar rows
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

When the document is ready I perform some operations on each data row like so:

```
$('.DataRow').each(function(){  //do stuff  } );
```

When the operations are complete for a particular row I wish to hide the 'imgProgress' in that row.
I am having trouble selecting the image so that I can set its display to 'none'

Currently I am trying it within th eloop like so:

```
$(this).find(.imgProgress')attr('display', 'none');
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I select the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$('#imgProgress').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Or even better $('.schedule-table img').hide();

Comment: again. won't work, he's got that ID on there incorrectly if that img repeats further down the page.

Comment: @walker You're a better man than I for reading through all that code carefully :)  Regardless, this would work, and he should fix his code as well.

Comment: I can either remove the id attribute or adjust the ids so they are unque. However, in the code, at the time I need to locate the first visible .imgProgress class that is not faded out, I won't know what row or id of image I need to work with, so getting the first instance of the  class that isn't faded out would be the best

Comment: @bengal - you can easily accomplish that with classes and javascript (jQuery), if you have problems post another question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `img` has an `id` (which ***must*** be unique within the document), use that:

```
$('#imgProgress');
```

To remove this from the document, you could use the jQuery [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

Comment: won't work, he's got that ID on there incorrectly if that img repeats further down the page.

Comment: @Walker, hence the emphasis. But, without clarification that he's using an `id` incorrectly, this will work. But, to be fair, I expect you're right.

Answer (score 1):

All of your cells have an ID on them that does not look unique. Append that ID in each TD to the class instead of as an ID.

Then:

```
$(this).children('.TD_Name').children('img').css('display', 'none'); //where "this" is the TR object
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#imgProgress", this)` or `$(this).find("#imgProgress")` would select the imageProgress ID if you're performing your jQuery on the `<td>`

Or change "this" to the ID/Class of your table row.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

Use `class="imgProgress"` instead

**JS**

Change it to

```
$(this).find('.imgProgress').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

ok for one thing. dont repeat IDs in the DOM is a bad idea and jquery only finds the 1st of a certain selector with that id.

if you are in a function for a certain tr you can change the img in that tr (with classes):

```
$('.DataRow').each(function(){ 
    //something in the tr...
    $($(this).children('td')[0]).children('.imgProgress').hide();
    //all done and hide this tr's img (in the 1st td)
})
```